# Error on installing "Microsoft ASP.NET Identity Core 2.2.0"

Tags: c#, asp.net, nuget, nuget-package

I get following error when i try to install Microsoft ASP.NET Identity Core 2.2.0 package:

Install failed Rolling back
Could not install package 'Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core 2.1.0'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETFramework,Version=v4.0', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.

I have tried same installation manually through "Manage Nuget Package". and i have even checked which .net version i am using. its 4.5.

Comment: "i have even checked which .net version i am using. its 4.5." The error message says otherwise. How did you establish that your project is **targeting** .Net4.5?

Comment: i think package that i am trying to install is compatible with .net 4.5 but not with 4.0. that's the reason i checked for .net framework version.

Comment: So, in the project properties (right-click the project node in the solution explorer and click properties), under "Application", the "Target Framework" is set to ".Net Framework 4.5"? Are you sure?

Comment: Ohh...i am using .net 4...so sry..

Comment: after changing my existing project from .net 4.0 to .net 4.5....it resolved my problem. here i just needed to read my error carefully. Thanks spender it really helped....really appreciate your help...

Comment: How can i find alternative to compare attribute which i am using on ViewModel Property?

Comment: That would be a separate question. Please don't turn this into a [chameleon question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions)...